# How to paginate a @Query query that is sorted? Java

Tags: java, spring

```
  @Query("select p.id,m.id,c.tipoDocumento,c.codigoFact from Corresponsable c"
         " inner join Pais p"
         " on p.id = c.pais.id"
         " inner join Moneda m"
         " on m.id = c.moneda.id"
         " order by p.nombre,m.nombre,c.tipoDocumento,c.codigoFact")
 List<Corresponsable> getFindPorCodPaisMonedaTipoDoc();
```

I did it this Query with JPA @Query in my Repository, but i would like to paginate my results with a number of page and numer of offset. What would be the best way to paginate keeping my values ​​ordered?

Comment: You should pass the sort order with the pageable as well

Comment: Given that you are using Spring, you probably want to read about the [Pagination features provided by the framework](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting).

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Data has native support to paginating, you can simply declare:

```
List<Corresponsable> getFindPorCodPaisMonedaTipoDoc(Pageable pageable).
```

You can manage the pagination with:

```
Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, Sort.by(sortBy));
```

For more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html